# Promise doesn't resolve the right value

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

```
function retRGObj(objName, xTime) {
    return new Promise(
        function (resolve, reject) {
            let data = {}
            findR(objName, xTime).then(function (msg) {
                data.R = msg
                console.log(data) //--> saves the expected value
            }).then(findG(objName, xTime).then(function (msg) {
                data.G = msg
                console.log(data) //--> saves the expected value
            }))
            console.log(data) //--> all values are gone, returned value is "Object {}"
            resolve(data)
        })
}
```

I don't know how I can not return the final value, it gets emptied in the last scope. How/why is it?

Comment: Just don't use the [promise constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572).

Comment: Also, you must pass a callback to `.then()`, not that `findG(…).then(…)` promise

Comment: Just for the reference, you're looking for `return Promise.all([findR(objName, xTime), findG(objName, xTime)]).then(function([msg1, msg2]) { let data = {R:msg1, G:msg2}; console.log(data); return data; })`

Comment: @Bergi Oh man thanks for this antipattern link as its educating, I didn't know about it and I am new to promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, `findR` and `findG` work *asynchronously*; otherwise, it would be weird that they return promises. So what you need to do is resolve *your* promise only when those promises complete. In your case, that would be within the callback to `findG(...).then`. Also, what you're passing into `findR(...).then` (the return value of `findG`) is highly suspect.

Here's a swing at it, but of course it depends on the details:

```
// If they have to be nested (one after another)
function retRGObj(objName, xTime) {
    return findR(objName, xTime).then((R) => {
        return findG(objName, xTime).then((G) => {
            return {R, G};
        });
    });
}
```

Or we can condense it further, because if an arrow function has just one expression in it and no `{}` around it, the result of that expression is its return value. So (not for the faint of heart!):

```
function retRGObj(objName, xTime) {
    return findR(objName, xTime).then(
        (R) => findG(objName, xTime).then(
            (G) => ({R, G})    // Note: The () around {R, G} matter
        )
    );
}
```

That waits for `findR` to finish before starting `findG`; I don't immediately see why that would be necessary, as I don't see anything in the call to `findG` that relies on the results from `findR`.

If they can be in parallel, then updating my earlier version based on [Bergi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739787/promise-doesnt-resolve-the-right-value/30739848#comment49535777_30739787), you can do this:

```
function retRGObj(objName, xTime) {
    return Promise.all(
        [findR(objName, xTime), findG(objName, xTime)]
    ).then(([R, G]) => {
         return {R, G};
    });
}
```

Or condensed:

```
function retRGObj(objName, xTime) {
    return Promise.all(
        [findR(objName, xTime), findG(objName, xTime)]
    ).then(([R, G]) => ({R, G}));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as I expected now, I am really new to promises and it seems I code it ugly and bad, yeah findG doesn't need anything from findR, I just couldn't be sure how to code it without a problem so I just chained it.

Comment: How to rewrite this without using arrow function expression; then(([R, G]) => {
         return {R, G};
    })

Comment: @Mehmet: Why do you not want arrow functions?

Comment: I am using nwjs, and "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>" but please keep the arrow function answer as it will be good for the records.

Comment: @Mehmet: You might want to switch to [Babel](https://babeljs.io) transpilation. But to remove the arrow functions from the un-condensed versions above, just put the word `function` in front of the arguments and remove the `=>`. So `(R) => { return {R, G}; }` becomes `function(R) { return {R, G}; }` (to switch over the condensed versions, you need to add the {} around the body as well).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh that's very nice, I'll take a look thank you for sharing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just a quick question tho, how would you normally write (([R, G]) => without arrow, because when I write function([R,G]) {
         return {R, G};
    } then I get: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: @Mehmet: That means that it doesn't handle "spread arguments," either, which are another feature of ES6 (not just arrow functions). So you'd have to use `function(result) { return {R: result[0], G: result[1]}`. I don't think I'd recommend continuing to use something with such dramatically spotty support for ES6 syntax. :-)